# Selector() ошибка в Swift 3

Tags: swift

Здравствуйте, обновила Swift 3, теперь на Selector() выходит ошибка, как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

прикольно. а зачем у вас вообще эта строка, она ничего не делает - там нет никакого селектора.

```
resetButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(someMethod), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Оу, я чего-то расстроилась и уже ничего не вижу, начала конвертировать, а он мне 3540 ошибок показал)

Answer (score 2):

Компилятор недвусмысленно говорит вам, что не может вызвать конструктор структуры Selector без параметров. Конструктор может принимать строковый параметр в явном виде:

```
resetButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("resetAction"), for: .touchUpInside)
```

, но в этом случае компилятор попросит использовать специальное выражение языка для создания селекторов:

```
resetButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(resetAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Использование этого выражения безопаснее строки (компилятор выдаст ошибку компиляции, если вы опечатаетесь), а также его удобнее изменять при рефакторинге.